# uninstall Zentyal

Tags: zentyal

I installed zentyal on one of my test servers but had a few issues with it and opted to have it removed. I remove the package repository from the sources list and used `apt-get remove zentyal` and `apt-get purge zentyal`and `apt-get autoclean && apt-get clean cache` But now I cannot install any package because it complains about dependencies with packages being replaced by zentyal e.g

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9 : Depends: libbind9-90 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
         Depends: libdns100 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
         Depends: libisc95 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
         Depends: libisccc90 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
         Depends: libisccfg90 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
         Depends: liblwres90 (= 1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5) but 2:9.9.5.dfsg-3+zentyal is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I have tried `apt-get update` with no success. I will try `apt-get upgrade` and see what comes out of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have to downgrade each package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbind9-90=1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5 libdns100=1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5 libisc95=1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5 libisccc90=1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5 libisccfg90=1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.5 liblwres90
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` did not cut it. Downgrading each of the packages did resolve the problem.